# Passing path to a file in resources folder to spring bean definition

Tags: spring, spring-bean

I have a spring bean definition as:

```
<bean class="...">
<property name="myFile" value="full\path\to\src\main\resources\a\b\myfile.dat"></property>
</bean>
```

This works fine. But its full path. I intend it to be like:

```
value="a\b\myfile.dat"
```

While trying to do so, I get FilesNotFoundException.

How to do it correctly?

Comment: How do you read your file?

Comment: I read file as: File file = new File(filename);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day,

You have to read a file through ClassPathResource, here is a good example - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access